# Using spring DI for providing mock data

Tags: spring

I'm new to spring, In my program I'm  using JSF + spring integration and for the UI testing I need to make mock data (by not using database).

I am going to use spring's Dependency injection for this. This is my data,

```
Vehicle ID    ---  veh101, veh102,veh103
Vehicle Type  ---  car, bus, bike
Vehicle color ---  Red, blue, white
```

`veh101`, `car`, `red` are description of a single object.
I have created a bean class `VehicleBean` with properties - `vehicleId`, `vechicleType` and `vechicleColor`

in the xml, I have given,

```
<bean id="VehicleBean" class="com.Vechicle.components.VechicleBean" scope="request">
   <property name="vehicleId" value="veh101" />   
   <property name="vechicleType" value="car" />
   <property name="vechicleColor" value="Red" />       
</bean>
```

These values are to be accessed in the UI by `#{value}`
so how do I refer/create objects for the rest of it,`veh102` and `veh103`?

Thanks in advance